I turned on my laptop then suddenly I'm having a problem on udisk2.service
This is what is on my screen when I turn on my laptop.


please read [ask] then [edit] your post accordingly

The line under the error message suggests what to do next. Please edit your question and add the output of the systemctl command.

Please [edit] your question and: i) tell us your Ubuntu version and flavor, ii) explain what the actual problem is. Does the machine boot OK after that message? Does it fail? Does it explode? What happens? iii) ask a question.

Is it trying to mount a Windows NTFS partition that has bitlocker on? Or fast startup which sets hibernation flag. Linux NTFS driver will not normally mount hibernated file systems to prevent damage when Windows restores it to was when hibernation created.
